# nmap to scan a list of endpoints (ip:port)

Tags: http-proxy, nmap, port-scanning, express-http-proxy

Is there a way to scan a big list of specific endpoints (IP:port) in [nmap](https://nmap.org/) without passing them individually? We have a list of IP:port that we want to run through the [http-open-proxy](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-open-proxy.html) script to verify which one are really open proxies to set up firewall rules. Since nmap parallelizes the list input (when provided with an IP list), is there a way to provide a list of endpoints as input?